# Jar does not open up (runs fine in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

So I have run into a problem: I have a little GUI-project I'm doing for fun's sake and it runs fine in Eclipse with no bugs and everything working as it should.

But when I export it to a runnable Jar then it won't work anymore. Basically nothing shows up at all, not even the JFrame.
I tried to make jars from other projects and they run fine so there shouldn't be any problem with my Java(Java JRE 8v40).

Here is the relevant code for you guys (comments are in German, so if there is something unknown, please ask):

**My Main-Method**

```
package paket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PokeMain {
    static int breite = 500;
    static int hoehe = 500;
    static PokeGui fenster;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fenster = new PokeGui();
        fenster.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fenster.setResizable(true);
        fenster.setSize(breite, hoehe);
        fenster.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        PokeGui.fight.requestFocus();//Fokus am Anfang
        fenster.requestFocusInWindow();//Fenster soll fokussierbar sein
        fenster.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        fenster.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void getFocus() {//sorgt dafuer, dass der Fokus auch nach Buttonklicks wieder im Fenster landen kann
        fenster.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

**My whole GUI-class**

```
package paket;
import java.awt .*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing .*;

public class PokeGui extends JFrame {
    static JPanel gesamtPanel, unteresPanel, aktionPanel, infoPanel, attackenPanel;//Container
    static JButton fight, bag, team, run;//Aktionen waehrend eines Kampfes
    static JButton attacke1, attacke2, attacke3, attacke4;
    BufferedReader br;//zum Lesen/Schreiben von Dateien
    static JProgressBar hpBar1, hpBar2;
    static JTextArea infoAnzeige;//einziges Element im infoPanel
    JLabel hp;
    Font schrift;
    PaintKampf pk;//Objekt der Klasse
    static int hp1 = 20, hp2 = 20;//1 = Spieler, 2 = Gegner

    public PokeGui() {
        super("Pokemon Java");

        Menueleiste ml = new Menueleiste();
        setJMenuBar(ml.actual_menu_bar);

        schrift = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 19);

        gesamtPanel = new JPanel();
        gesamtPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gesamtPanel.setFocusable(true);
        gesamtPanel.setBounds(0, 0, PokeMain.breite, PokeMain.hoehe);
        add(gesamtPanel);

        pk = new PaintKampf();//Objekt der Klasse PaintKampf(JLabel)
        pk.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
        gesamtPanel.add(pk);

        hpBar1 = new JProgressBar(0, hp1);//Meine HP
        hpBar1.setValue(hp1);
        hpBar1.setFont(schrift);
        hpBar1.setString("HP: " + hp1);
        hpBar1.setStringPainted(true);
        hpBar1.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        hpBar1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //      gesamtPanel.add(hpBar1,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        hpBar2 = new JProgressBar(0, hp2);//Gegner HP
        hpBar2.setValue(hp2);
        hpBar2.setString("HP: " + hp2);
        hpBar2.setStringPainted(true);
        hpBar2.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        hpBar2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //      gesamtPanel.add(hpBar2,BorderLayout.EAST);

        unteresPanel = new JPanel();//enthaelt Aktionen wahrend eines Kampfes sowie Textanzeige waehrenddessen
        unteresPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        gesamtPanel.add(unteresPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        infoAnzeige = new JTextArea("What should your POKéMON\ndo?");
        infoAnzeige.setLineWrap(false);
        infoAnzeige.setOpaque(false);//durchsichtig
        infoAnzeige.setEditable(false);
        infoAnzeige.setFocusable(false);
        infoAnzeige.setForeground(new Color(30, 60, 240));
        infoAnzeige.setFont(schrift);

        infoPanel = new JPanel();//ganz unten links
        infoPanel.add(infoAnzeige);//fuegt das JTextArea zum Panel hinzu
        infoPanel.setBackground(new Color(240, 255, 255));
        unteresPanel.add(infoPanel);

        aktionPanel = new JPanel();//ganz unten rechts
        aktionPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        aktionPanel.setFocusable(true);
        unteresPanel.add(aktionPanel);//fuegt es dem "uebergeordneten" Panel hinzu
        aktionPanel.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());

        attackenPanel = new JPanel();//ganz unten rechts
        attackenPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        attackenPanel.setVisible(false);

        //Initialisierung der Buttons sowie Auslesen der Attackennamen
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/Player_Attacken.txt"));
            attacke1 = new JButton(br.readLine());//liest aus der Datei die jeweilige Zeile aus und geht dann zur naechsten Zeile
            attacke2 = new JButton(br.readLine());
            attacke3 = new JButton(br.readLine());
            attacke4 = new JButton(br.readLine());
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException io) {
        }

        attacke1.setContentAreaFilled(false);//macht alles ausser dem Inhalt unsichtbar
        attacke1.setFont(schrift);
        attackenPanel.add(attacke1);
        attacke1.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        attacke1.addActionListener(new ActionHandler_Kampf());

        attacke2.setContentAreaFilled(false);//macht alles ausser dem Inhalt unsichtbar
        attacke2.setFont(schrift);
        attackenPanel.add(attacke2);
        attacke2.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        attacke2.addActionListener(new ActionHandler_Kampf());

        attacke3.setContentAreaFilled(false);//macht alles ausser dem Inhalt unsichtbar
        attacke3.setFont(schrift);
        attackenPanel.add(attacke3);
        attacke3.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        attacke3.addActionListener(new ActionHandler_Kampf());

        attacke4.setContentAreaFilled(false);//macht alles ausser dem Inhalt unsichtbar
        attacke4.setFont(schrift);
        attackenPanel.add(attacke4);
        attacke4.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        attacke4.addActionListener(new ActionHandler_Kampf());

        fight = new JButton("FIGHT");
        fight.setBorderPainted(false);//macht die Raender unsichtbar
        //      fight.setContentAreaFilled(false);//macht alles ausser dem Inhalt unsichtbar
        fight.setBackground(Color.RED);
        fight.setFont(schrift);
        aktionPanel.add(fight);
        fight.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        fight.addActionListener(new ActionHandler_Kampf());

        bag = new JButton("BAG");
        bag.setFont(schrift);
        bag.setBorderPainted(false);
        bag.setBackground(new Color(218, 165, 32));
        aktionPanel.add(bag);
        bag.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        bag.addActionListener(new ActionHandler_Kampf());

        team = new JButton("POKéMON");
        team.setFont(schrift);
        team.setBorderPainted(false);
        team.setBackground(new Color(50, 205, 50));
        aktionPanel.add(team);
        team.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        team.addActionListener(new ActionHandler_Kampf());

        run = new JButton("RUN");
        run.setFont(schrift);
        run.setBorderPainted(false);
        run.setBackground(new Color(30, 144, 255));
        aktionPanel.add(run);
        run.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        run.addActionListener(new ActionHandler_Kampf());

        //      gesamtPanel.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

**And here is my paintComponent-Method where I draw the images.**

```
package paket;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class PaintKampf extends JLabel {
    Image kampf_hintergrund, P1, P2;//Hintergrund
    URL link, linkP1, linkP2;//URL des Bildes

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {//paint-Methode
        super.paintComponent(g);
        try {
            link = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/pwkzzgv.png");
        }//holt sich das Bild von diesem Link
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            kampf_hintergrund = ImageIO.read(link);
        }//setzt das Bild gleich der URL
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            linkP1 = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/dg5xRUy.png");
        }//holt sich das Bild von diesem Link
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            P1 = ImageIO.read(linkP1);
        }//Spieler 1
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            linkP2 = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/fdZyPbr.png");
        }//holt sich das Bild von diesem Link
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            P2 = ImageIO.read(linkP2);
        }//Spieler 2
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        g.drawImage(kampf_hintergrund, 0, 0, null);//zeichnet das Hintergrundbild
        g.drawImage(P1, 0, 200, null);
        g.drawImage(P2, 350, 90, null);
    }
}
```

I can't post any images yet but as I said, in Eclipse there appears to be no problem with the program itself.

Comment: please post information about how you are compiling and running the jar. That seems a more likely place for the error to be, than in the code itself.

Comment: First, I think you should stick to best practices and use SwingUtilities in you main method. Furthermore how do you start your program? You should probably use something like java -jar <yourjarname>.jar

Comment: To run the jar I just used doubleclick, you know, like a regular .exe file in Windows.                                                                                                    Well, I experimented a bit and found the issue(I don't know why it's like that but I assume that's Java lol...): it has to do with my JButtons in my Gui Class where I take the x.-line from a .txt file.                                         Changing the access(so using http instead of a local file) has solved this problem so everything is shown up as it should.